# Getting value from one table and querying another with that value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following tables:

```
TableA
---------------
ParamA ¦ ParamB
---------------
  695  ¦  Test

TableB
---------------
ParamA ¦ ParamC
---------------
  695  ¦ Test2
```

So I am trying to create a stored procedure that will `SELECT ParamA FROM TableA WHERE ParamB = @ParamB` and `UPDATE ParamC = 'NULL'` in `TableB WHERE ParamA = ParamA FROM TableA`

What I have so far is this:

```
UPDATE ClassDetails
SET ValidTo = 'NULL'
WHERE Class = Classes.ClassId AND Classes.ClassName = @ClassName;
```

I know the above is wrong but that is my logic regarding it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of hard to follow your reasoning but if I *did* understood you correct, following update would suit your needs.

```
UPDATE b
SET    ParamC = NULL
FROM   TableB b
       INNER JOIN TableA a ON a.ParamA = b.ParamA
WHERE  a.ParamB = @ParamB
```

Syntax for [UPDATE FROM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> FROM < table_source >
>
> Specifies that a table is used to
>   provide the criteria for the update
>   operation.

Comment: Perfect just what I was after!